# Custom Objects and related lists

Tags: metadata-api, page-layout

I've been able to create a few custom objects through the metadata API.  The both have Contact related fields. How can I:

A. Make related lists for these objects show up on the contacts page programmatically?

B. Change the format of the related lists.  By default, they just show name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Metdata API both problem can be solved.

**A.** By metadata API get page-layouts for objects you created and modify there metadata as you want. However, it would be complex.

B. With page-layouts you also get related list configuration. So, there you can add/remove fields/buttons.

Sample payload:

```
<relatedLists>
        <excludeButtons>New</excludeButtons>
        <fields>NAME</fields>
        <fields>Assigned_To__c</fields>
        <fields>Case__c</fields>
        <fields>Case_Status__c</fields>
        <fields>ActivityType__c</fields>
        <fields>Subject__c</fields>
        <fields>Description__c</fields>
        <fields>Start_Date_Time__c</fields>
        <fields>End_Date_Time__c</fields>
        <fields>CREATEDBY_USER</fields>
        <relatedList>CaseActivity__c.Account__c</relatedList>
        <sortField>Start_Date_Time__c</sortField>
        <sortOrder>Desc</sortOrder>
    </relatedLists>
```

It is up to you how you would read those payloads.